# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Wireless Card Not Functioning

Tags: wireless

Having an issue where my wireless card seems to be recognized by OS but that's about it. No SSIDs are visible. Ethernet is working fine. Linked is the output of some script I found: https://pastebin.com/zuQ8Nc0Q

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Try 20.04 Live installer, check Wifi working or not.